# Problems executing an Android application which uses GoogleMaps .apk in a smartphone

Tags: android, google-maps

I have recently developed an Android application which uses the GoogleMaps API and represents the points of the map. The application works well in the Android emulator , but it does not work when it is executed in a SmartPhone. When the map is represented all the points are shown but the map is not shown (it appears a white map with squares). I have generated the .apk whith the `default.keystore` : `debug.keystore`. I have tried to generate the .apk with a customized keystore and obtain the following result :

> Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect.

Any solution for the program of the API of googlemaps in the smartphone?
Does anybody know how to generate a new `debug.keystore`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a new keystore. use this new keystore for getting google map api key then run

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to make a new debug keystore is actually to let the tools do it for you. If you delete the existing keystore, the build tools will automatically generate a new one for you. Then, you can do the steps to get the hash and get the API key:

The default storage location for AVDs is in ~/.android/ on OS X and Linux, in C:\Documents and Settings\.android\ on Windows XP, and in C:\Users\.android\ on Windows Vista and Windows 7.

The next time you build, the build tools will regenerate a new keystore and debug key.

Full description of steps here: http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html

Answer (score 0):

You could use the same keystore as it is, to the device as well. The same keystore works for emulator as well